# Iterate List in Reverse from a specific Index

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am trying to iterate a list in a reverse order from a specific index.

My list looks something like this for example: 4 5 8 7

What I want to do is traverse the list backwards from whatever index that 8 is on. So my new list will look something like: 8 5 4 7.

```
for(int j = newPlayerList.size(); j >= maxIndex; j--) {
        newPlayerList2.add(newPlayerList.get(j % newPlayerList.size()));
    } //max index is the index of the highest number in the list, i already store this in a different function
```

This is what I have so far. My order isnt being preserved properly and I am kind of lost on where to go from here.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Thanks for the answers guys. My implementation was something like this: 
for(int j = 0; j < playerList.size(); j++) {
newPlayerList.add(playerList.get((maxIndex - j + playerList.size()) % playerList.size()));
}
In case anyone ever gets into this like I did. Was stuck on this for almost 4 hrs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Collections.rotate` in combination with `Collections.reverse` with out the need of a new list or a for loop:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    //original: 4 5 8 7
    //expected: 8 5 4 7
    
    List<Integer>  mylist = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(4,5,8,7));
    System.out.println("Original List : " + mylist);

    int distance = mylist.indexOf(8) + 1;
    Collections.reverse(mylist);
    Collections.rotate(mylist, distance);

    System.out.println("Rotated List: " + mylist);
}
```

Comment: but if 'index' would be an integer field in the sorted class ex. 'PlayerEntity', Comparator method could be easier to deploy.

Comment: Can you elaborate? I have the integer field mapped to a field in the player class. I just didnt know how to rotate the annoying list on an index.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this is what you're trying to do:

```
for (int j = maxIndex; j >= 0; j--) {
    newPlayerList2.add(newPlayerList.get(j));
}
for (int j = newPlayerList.size() - 1; j > maxIndex; j--) {
    newPlayerList2.add(newPlayerList.get(j));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not experienced in operating lambdas, streams, but please try this method:

```
private static List<Integer> iterateListByIndex(List<Integer> list, int factor) {

    Comparator<Integer> integerComparator = new Comparator<Integer>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(Integer o1, Integer o2) {
            // factor < 0 -> reversed order
            return Integer.compare(o1, o2) * (factor);
        }
    };

    Collections.sort(list, integerComparator);
    return list;
}
```

and use it ex.

```
    List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(8, 5, 4, 7));

    System.out.println(list.toString());
    list = iterateListByIndex(list, -1);
    System.out.println(list.toString());
```

results could be:

```
[8, 5, 4, 7]

[8, 7, 5, 4]
```

Comment: Looks like you posted your answer under the wrong question.